# FireBase Cloud Messaging - how to open a link instead of Activity from notification in Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FireBase Cloud Messaging in Unity. I want to open a link when the user clicks on the arrived message from FireBase Cloud Messaging.

In Firebase panel I set custom data "click_action" with a URL value to message, and I receive it when clicking on notification in OnMessageReceived method like :

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Log("Received Data: " + e.Message.Data["click_action"]);        
}
```

When I add code like

```
Application.OpenURL(e.Message.Data["click_action"]);
```

in OnMessageReceived, the link opens but the application also will open when taping on received notification.

How can prevent application to open when clicking on FCM message in Unity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the ACTION_VIEW Intent?

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action");
    String url = "http://your.url.here";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm using FCM in Unity game engine not in android native.

Comment: @user1579019did you got any solution? I'm also looking for the same.